# unable to provide vs. unable of providing

Tags: word-choice

Someone proof read a document I've been working on and made the following amendment. I would like know which one is correct or sounds better. Please develop your answer.

> ...such strategies are unable to provide continuous benefits

to

> ...such strategies are unable of providing continuous benefits

Comment: I am not asking anyone to proofread for me. It is just an honest punctual question about grammar, I would like to know when to use one or the other properly though.

Comment: Well, I suppose. I didn't vote to close, now that I think about it.

Comment: I think this is just too basic. Just Googling **"unable to"** and **"unable of"** gives 500M hits compared to 0.4M, which imho is all a non-native speaker needs to know.

Comment: I disagree completely, FF. That's like saying all an engineer needs to know is what previous bridges have looked like; no need for stress analysis and still less for calculus in making new ones.

Comment: I don't think a Google search is a reliable source. Either way, I appreciate the feedback. This will probably be useful to others as well, as basic as it is.

Comment: Those who had voted to close better thing again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's really very simple.

*Able* (and *unable*) **can** take infinitive complements, so the first one is grammatical. 
But they **can't** take gerunds, even with epenthetic prepositions, so the second one is **not** grammatical.

You may be confusing *able* with *capable* (and *incapable*), which means something similar, and which **does** take a gerund complement with *of*:

- *such strategies are capable of providing continuous benefits.*

and doesn't take an infinitive:

- **such strategies are capable to provide continuous benefits.*

Comment: This is really informative. Thank you. If I could I'd tick your answer twice. :)